# Customizing __delattr__ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is the following a valid `__delattr__` method?

```
class Item:
    def __delattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.__dict__:
            print ('Deleting attribute: %s' % attr)
            super().__delattr__(attr)
        else:
            print ('Already deleted this attribute!')
```

Specifically, is the `super()` the proper way to "actually delete" the attributes? And is the `attr in self.__dict__` the proper way to check if an attribute is in an instance?

Comment: I think `hasattr(self, attr)` would be better as it checks the instance, class and superclass(es).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super would call the corresponding method of the parent class, you can implement your own special method here and don't need to refer to its super implementation. Consider the following:

```py
class Item:
    def __delattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            print ('Deleting attribute: %s' % attr)
            del self.__dict__[attr]
        except KeyError:
            print ('Already deleted this attribute!')
```

Testing the class:

```
>>> i.test = 'a value'
>>> del i.test
Deleting attribute: test
>>> del i.test
Deleting attribute: test
Already deleted this attribute!
```